# Parallelism of OpaqueTridentKafkaSpout is one after being submitted in cluster mode

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-storm

I'm using storm with OpaqueTridentKafkaSpout. However, the parallelism of spout is one after being submitted.

```
    BrokerHosts zk = new ZkHosts("xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx");
    TridentKafkaConfig spoutConf = new TridentKafkaConfig(zk, "xx","xxx");
    spoutConf.scheme = new SchemeAsMultiScheme(new StringScheme());
    OpaqueTridentKafkaSpout dataSpout = new OpaqueTridentKafkaSpout(spoutConf);
```

[image]

All config params are following.

```
Config conf = new Config();
    conf.setDebug(false);
    conf.setNumWorkers(100);
    conf.setNumAckers(200);
    conf.setMaxTaskParallelism(200);
    conf.setMaxSpoutPending(500);
```

What should I do? Thanks very much!

---

*update with 2016-01-22 11:00:00*

I try changed  add spout type to the

```
   `OpaqueTridentKafkaSpout dataSpout1 = new OpaqueTridentKafkaSpout(spoutConf);
    OpaqueTridentKafkaSpout dataSpout2 = new OpaqueTridentKafkaSpout(spoutConf);
    TridentTopology topology = new TridentTopology();
    Stream stream1 = topology.newStream("dataSpout1",dataSpout1).name("dataSpout1");
    Stream stream2 = topology.newStream("dataSpout2",dataSpout2).name("dataSpout2");
    Stream stream =  topology.merge(stream1,stream2);`
```

is also fail...

Comment: Not sure what your question is, but you can set the parallelism in `TridentTopologyBuilder.setSpout(String id, String streamName, String txStateId, ITridentSpout spout, Integer parallelism, String batchGroup)`

Comment: Thanks, but TridentTopologyBuilder.setSpout() accepts IBatchSpout and ITridentSpout. However I'd like to use OpaqueTridentKafkaSpout.

Comment: How do you add your spout to the topology right now? I am not familiar with OpaqueTridentKafkaSpout...

Comment: I'm add spout with 
        `TridentTopology topology = new TridentTopology();
        Stream stream = topology.newStream("dataSpout",dataSpout).name("dataSpout");
        topology.merge(stream);
        stream = stream.each(dataSpout.getOutputFields(),new LogFunction(),new Fields("urlType","date","hour","day","data")).name("logFunction");`

Comment: I found that TridentTopology.build() invokes TridentTopologyBuilder.setSpout(String id, String streamName, String txStateId, ITridentSpout spout, Integer parallelism, String batchGroup). However, after debugging, I found that the value of parameter parallelism whatever it is, the parallelism of spout in running topology is always one.

Comment: Did you try `topology.newStream("dataSpout",dataSpout).parallelismHint(...)` ?

Comment: Yes,I've already tried this.

Comment: I never used this by myself. Maybe it's bug. I would recommend to ask at the dev-list: https://storm.apache.org/getting-help.html